# Posting Json object to an external API from asp.net mvc action method

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, rest, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to integrate with a 3rd party Rest API. Now the API have the following definition for a Create operation:-

```
> URL :-  https://<IP address>:7272/restapi/json/v1/resources?AUTHTOKEN
> HTTP METHOD: POST
> 
> Sample Requests
> 
> curl -X POST -k -H "Content-Type: text/json" 
> 'https://IP:7272/restapi/json/v1/resources?AUTHTOKEN=***'
> -d  'INPUT_DATA={"operation":{"Details":{"RESOURCENAME":"Windows  Server","ACCOUNTNAME":"Administrator","RESOURCETYPE":"Windows","PASSWORD"
> :"Test123#@!","NOTES":"Testing 
> API","RESOURCEURL":"http://windowsserver/adminconsole","RESOURCECUSTOMFIEL
> D":[{"CUSTOMLABEL":"Secure Resource","CUSTOMVALUE":"YES"}]}}}'
```

so can anyone advice how I can post JSON to the API from my action method? I usually use WebClient.DownloadString to receive json from the API,, but not sure how I can send json object ?

Answer (score 1):

On how to send a POST request, look here for example: [HTTP request with post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/http-request-with-post)

For creating the JSON data, you could use a library like the excellent Json.NET http://www.newtonsoft.com/json or build the string on your own.